# Caching query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

I want to perform a search on dataset with 100k entries. I am using elasticsearch and following is my query:

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'filter': {
        'bool': {
          'must': [
            {
              'term': {
                'is_profiled': true
              }
            },
            {
              'range': {
                'profile_completion': {
                  'gte': '37'
                }
              }
            },
            {
              'bool': {
                'should': [
                  {
                    'geo_distance': {
                      'distance': '70km',
                      'address.place.location': '12.9715987, 77.5945627'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          'must_not': [
            {
              'exists': {
                'field': 'is_staffing_employee'
              }
            }
          ],
          'should': {
            'match_phrase': {
              'functional_areas.name': 'Sales / Business Development'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  '_source': false,
  'size': 1000
}
```

Now, this query is taking a lot of time (in some cases around 10 seconds). I was wondering is there a way where we can make it fast by caching the query components (some are static components in my query). I read about the caches in elasticsearch (node query cache, shard request cache etc.) but all seems to be caching the result (which is post) and my use case is such that I need to query once only. Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

How about [eagerly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/preload-fielddata.html#eager-fielddata) loading fielddata to preload the fields contents to memory?

This makes sure the in-memory cache has already populated before you fire a query.

For latest versions you can look into [preloading data into file-system cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_pre_loading_data_into_the_file_system_cache.html).

Comment: Is this available in newer elasticsearch version? I am using elasticsearch 5.6 version.

Comment: Updated my answer